# How to integrate LinkedIn 2FA into Microsoft Authenticator?

Tags: apps

I am using MS Authenticator app on my Lumia. I already have Facebook, Microsoft and Google in it. But can't figure out how to integrate LinkedIn 2FA into it, is it possible?

I've read LinkedIn forums, but could not find concrete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The article on LinkedIn blog](http://blog.linkedin.com/2013/05/31/protecting-your-linkedin-account-with-two-step-verification/) and also [this](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/544/) say that LinkedIn 2FA works on SMS, they don't mention any authentication apps. In LinkedIn settings page authentication with app option is not found.

Moreover, this [thread from LinkedIn community forum](http://community.linkedin.com/questions/3748/two-factor-authentication.html) makes it clear that 2FA is not available via app.